# iPhone exchange and server error, can't get mail

Tags: iphone, exchange

I have an iPhone that is having problems syncing email only with exchange 2003.  Contacts and Calendar items sync fine.  It's also only with 1 account.  I can delete the account on the iPhone and sync it to another one just fine.

Has anyone run into this before?  Is there a log on the iPhone where I can see the specific error?

Thanks,

Comment: Is your phone jailbroken?

Comment: Is anything encrypted (Exchange)?

Comment: @Systech - Nope.
@Admin alive - Nope.

I'm currently assuming a corrupted email in the inbox.  Moving everything out to a .pst.  We'll see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here was the problem.  The inbox had a corrupt message.  I moved the mailbox to a different mailstore (using the move with errors option) Once that finished, everything is happy again.